# contacts screen

Tags: iphone

i want to display no of contacts in the table view like iPhone native phone app how can i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [blog](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=240).

Start by looking at ABAddressBook which will allow you to retrieve address book records. It is well [documented](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone.pdf) by Apple.

Then you can use this data to populate a UITableView with UITableView cells representing the records. Again, both of these classes are well documented by apple and here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to display the user's contact list is using the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` class in the AddressBookUI framework. It'll handle pretty much all of the UI for you; you just need to implement its delegate methods (look up the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate` protocol).